# How to embed Facebook "Invite Your Friends" plugin into my website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Anyone know about this? I am trying to embed that plugin and am lost. I have already tried this and this is not working at all. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form

A help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the article :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Facebook_App_ASP_Csharp2.aspx

I hope that would definitely help you.

Comment: Yes I did try this too but no luck also. What I think is that this would only work for applications that are hosted on Facebook. I want the functionality on my website. Am I right?